# Communicate with PC without using USB port with Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino Micro that connects to my computer over USB and acts as a joystick. I want to know the delay between a joystick signal being sent and the signal being received by a remote machine, and so I need to harvest timing data from the Arduino. However, I cannot send this timing data over USB as the USB port is already in use as a HID device.

Is it possible to communicate using some of the spare digital pins on the chip? For instance, can I connect from the digital pins (as serial) into a spare USB port on my computer? I'd like to know how this is achieved on both a software level and a hardware level (that is, how do I physically connect digital pins through to a USB port?)

I'm sure that this is a solved problem but I can't find any good examples. Can anyone provide some?

Comment: Not sure if this works on micro: [SoftwareSerial Library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial). Also, there is an Arduino SE you might try: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks, I think I can use that serial library with a TTL/USB adapter cable similar to this: https://www.adafruit.com/product/954 to make the connection. I'll write an answer to this question in a few days if I can get it to work!

Comment: Check out this article for information abaout the latency: http://neophob.com/2010/11/arduino-serial-latency/

Comment: Why would you want to use software serial when you have a hardware one available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a USB to TTL converter. In arduino simply write data to serial port using `SoftwareSerial` library which allows you to use any digital pins for serial communication. Then connect the USB-TTL with arduino digital pins you set in your program.

For example in arduino:

```
SoftwareSerial softSerial(rxPin, txPin);
........
........
void Setup()
{
   softSerial.begin(9600);
   softSerial.println("hello");
}
```

Connections:

```
USB-TTL     Arduino
Tx -------  rxPin
Rx  ------- txPin
Gnd ------- Gnd
```

If all you want to do is to get the data on your PC then you can use any terminal program including Arduino IDE Serial monitor to display the data coming from your spare digital pins. But make sure to display the data on Serial monitor you need to select the **com port** of the USB-TTL adapter from **Tools>Port**.

Comment: Again, why would someone want to use software serial when you have a hardware one available?

Comment: hardware serial will be used for arduino communication as an HID device

Comment: No. The USB is a standalone module, it doesn't need "hardware serial".
You can check the schematic of the board and the MCU datasheet. The UART and the USB are two different modules.
You have access to the hardware serial through RX and TX avaiable on the Arduino Micro board.

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't notice it's arduino micro. In my mind it was Arduino Uno as a joystick like the one i tried. HardareSerial will work fine

Comment: Just to clarify for any future visitors: It is necessary to use the software serial library for the Arduino Micro. I tried using hardware serial (pins 0 and 1) but sending serial output through these pins causes the virtual arudino joystick to become faulty. I instead used software serial on pins 10/11).